# Python object methods dict

Tags: python, methods, dictionary

I need to have a class instance variable that contains a list of handlers (the specified methods of this class instance). The list of handlers is available upon request.

I have two solutions, but none of them does not suit me.

1. http://www.ideone.com/3aSkT - You will get a cyclic reference. GC can clean it up, but we do not know when.
2. http://www.ideone.com/OaP5c - Here, when you call, you need to explicitly pass instance of the class to the function.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I changed the question for better understanding.

Comment: Why are you worrying about circular references?  Python will take care of it for you.

Comment: Why don't you use method names? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: http://www.ideone.com/rztZT further advance

Answer (score 2):

If I got you right, you could simply use the built-in function [`dir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir). Example:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def m1(self):
...         pass
...     def m2(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> dir(Foo)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'm1', 'm2']
>>> [m for m in dir(Foo) if '__' not in m]
['m1', 'm2']
```

---

**EDIT:** Your question and your comments aren't truly clear. It would help if you could edit your question mentioning your expected outcome. My best guess, reading your comment here below (*"I need to have this dictionary `{int type: method type}`"*) would be that you might want:

```
>>> dict(enumerate([getattr(Foo, m) for m in dir(Foo) if '__' not in m]))
{0: <unbound method Foo.m1>, 1: <unbound method Foo.m2>}
```

---

**EDIT2:** Looking at your latest pastebins, when you write:

```
packet_ids_to_check_up = (0x0404, 0x0405, 0x0404, 0x0505, 0x0506)
    for packet_id in packet_ids_to_check_up:
        if packet_id in some_class_obj:
            some_class_obj[packet_id]('Hello world')
```

it seems you expect to have your class acting as a dictionary. If this is the case, you should probably take a look at the [`collections.abc`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.abc.html) module, and in particular the `MutableMapping` class. From the [python glossary](http://docs.python.org/dev/glossary.html#term-mapping):

> **mapping** - A container object that supports arbitrary key lookups and implements the methods specified in the Mapping or MutableMapping abstract base classes. Examples include dict, collections.defaultdict, collections.OrderedDict and collections.Counter.

This would imply implementing the following methods:

- `__contains__`
- `keys`
- `items`
- `values`
- `get`
- `__eq__`
- `__ne__`
- `pop`
- `popitem`
- `clear`
- `update`
- `setdefault`

However, from your code is not really self-evident why you couldn't just get away with using a simple dictionary (or eventually subclassing `dict` directly...).

Does this help?

Comment: This will keep only the names of the required methods, but not objects. And I need to have this dictionary {int type: method type}

Comment: @Miatar - See my edit. Leave a comment if I still did not guess. :)

Comment: No, the key values ​​are not consistent. I think it's time to say that I'm writing a bot for the MMO, and the keys in this case are the identifiers of packets.

Comment: @Miatar - I looked at the last pastebins you posted: more edit in my answer.

Comment: The main problem was not in the choice of container, but the fact that if we keep object methods within the object it creates a circular reference and does not allow the object to be destroyed by a reference count, when we leaving the scope. Sometimes it is very important.

Comment: Python uses two kind of GC - the "standart" one, and the "ref count" one. Thats why is has GIL and all problems with it.

Comment: @Miatar - Object methods are always within objects... :-/ Can you update your question with an example of the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: @mac by object methods i mean closures - the functions that already know which object they belong. Example http://www.ideone.com/2EGKW

Comment: @Ned Batchelder i removed, nothing changed, the object is still lives: http://www.ideone.com/CIE8P

Comment: @Ned Batchelder yes - i know eventually object will be GC'ed. And thanks for your tip about __del__ - this really removed some memory leak's.

Answer (score 1):

Extending the answer of @mac taking in account the OP asked for a class instance variable and that he could also want to get info on "private" methods:

```
In [5]: class Foo(object):
   ...:     def m1(self):pass
   ...:     def m2(self):pass
   ...:
In [6]: f = Foo()
In [7]: lst = dir(f)
In [8]: [m for m in lst if not m.endswith('__')]
Out[8]: ['m1', 'm2']
```

If you want the object method:

```
In [17]: getattr(Foo, 'm1')
Out[17]: <unbound method Foo.m1>
```

or directly in the list comprehension from the instance:

```
In [18]: [getattr(f, m) for m in lst if not m.endswith('__')]
Out[18]:
[<bound method Foo.m1 of <__main__.Foo object at 0x00000000073DD1D0>>,
 <bound method Foo.m2 of <__main__.Foo object at 0x00000000073DD1D0>>]
```

Edit: So, given the examples you give in your link, maybe you are looking for something like:

```
class SomeClass:

    store = {0: 'someMethod', 1: 'someMethod1'}

    def __init__(self):
        print('__init__')

    def __del__(self):
        print('__del__')

    def get_dict(self):
        return [getattr(self, att) for idx, att in SomeClass.store.items()]

    def someMethod(): pass
    def someMethod1(): pass


f = SomeClass()
print f.get_dict()
```

That prints:

```
__init__
[<bound method SomeClass.someMethod of <__main__.SomeClass instance at 0x0000000
0026E2E08>>, <bound method SomeClass.someMethod1 of <__main__.SomeClass instance
 at 0x00000000026E2E08>>]
__del__
```

Comment: Thanks for getattr, but this still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Then that means I'm not able to understand your question. Could you clarify it?. Maybe you could give an example of what you want to get and how you want to ask for it? That would help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand your problem, but if you want to "map" method names to other methods (calling `Foo().store()` would in fact call `Foo().someMethod()`) without referencing them, you can do this by overriding the default `object.__getattribue__` behaviour.

```
class Foo(object):
    mapping = {'store': 'someMethod'}

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        try:
            # first check if it's a "regular" attribute/method
            return super(Foo, self).__getattribute__(attr)
        except AttributeError:
            # attribute was not found, if it's not in your mapping, re-raise the error
            if attr not in self.mapping:
                raise
            mapped_attr = self.mapping[attr]
            return super(Foo, self).__getattribute__(mapped_attr)

    def someMethod(self):
        print "Foo().someMethod()"

foo = Foo()
foo.store()
```

Output:

```
>>> Foo().someMethod()
```

Comment: For refactoring reasons i dont want to store method names in text.